# how to exchange value between 2 inputs

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have 2 input text and button.. I want to make exchange value between 2 inputs at the same time. here is my code.

```js
$("button").on('click', function() {
    if (!($(this).hasClass("clicked"))) {
        $(this).addClass("clicked");
        $(".first").val($(".second").val());
        $(".second").val($(".first").val());
    } else {
        $(this).removeClass("clicked");
        $(".first").val($(".second").val());
        $(".second").val($(".first").val());
    }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <input class="first" type="text" value>
  <input class="second" type="text" value>
  <button type="button">Exchange</button>
</div>
```

the first input works fine but the second not working.. I want the exchange happen at the same time.

Comment: `$(".first").val($(".second").val());
        $(".second").val($(".first").val());` Guess the value of `($(".first")` after the first statement. You need an extra variable to save one of the value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are overwriting one of the two before reading that other value. So you end up with twice the same value.

The traditional way is to use a temporary variable:

```js
$("button").on('click', function() {
    $(this).toggleClass("clicked");
    var temp = $(".first").val();
    $(".first").val($(".second").val());
    $(".second").val(temp);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <input class="first" type="text" value>
  <input class="second" type="text" value>
  <button type="button">Exchange</button>
</div>
```

At the same time note how you can shorten your code with the `toggleClass` method.

#### Alternative

Just to provide an alternative, you *can* do this without an explicit extra variable, using the ES6 [destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment). For that to work, you need to have an assignable property for the `input` value. Of course, the DOM `value` property would just be that:

```js
$("button").on('click', function() {
    $(this).toggleClass("clicked");
    [$(".first").get(0).value, $(".second").get(0).value] = 
            [$(".second").val(), $(".first").val()];
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <input class="first" type="text" value>
  <input class="second" type="text" value>
  <button type="button">Exchange</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

that because the value was changed . try to save old value on var

```js
$("button").on('click', function() {
    var first = $(".first").val(),
        second = $(".second").val(); 
   
    if (!($(this).hasClass("clicked"))) {
        $(this).addClass("clicked");
        $(".first").val(second);
        $(".second").val(first);
    } else {
        $(this).removeClass("clicked");
        $(".first").val(second);
        $(".second").val(first);
    }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <input class="first" type="text" value>
  <input class="second" type="text" value>
  <button type="button">Exchange</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$("button").on('click', function() {
    var firstVal = $(".first").val()
    var secondVal = $(".second").val()
    if (!($(this).hasClass("clicked"))) {
        $(this).addClass("clicked");
        $(".first").val(secondVal);
        $(".second").val(firstVal);
    } else {
        $(this).removeClass("clicked");
        $(".first").val(secondVal);
        $(".second").val(firstVal);
    }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <input class="first" type="text" value>
  <input class="second" type="text" value>
  <button type="button">Exchange</button>
</div>
```

You need to store the original values first, when you try to swap them without storing you forget that one of the values is overridden.

Answer (score 0):

Use an intermediate temp variable to swap them.

```
$("button").on('click', function() {
    if (!($(this).hasClass("clicked"))) {
        $(this).addClass("clicked");
        var temp = $(".first").val();
        $(".first").val($(".second").val());
        $(".second").val(temp);
    } else {
        $(this).removeClass("clicked");
        var temp = $(".first").val();
        $(".first").val($(".second").val());
        $(".second").val(temp);
    }
});
```

[Working DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/nutboltu/71uadtrq/1/)